# Converting HeapByteBuffer to UUID

Tags: spring, converters

My application is based on Spring reactive, mysql. When I try to get a data from mysql db I get an error "org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.nio.HeapByteBuffer] to type [java.util.UUID]"

I've tried to add converter to WebConfig which implements WebFluxConfigurer, however when Spring is looking up for the converter it cannot find because of ByteBuffer and not HeapByteBuffer (this class is protected which extends ByteBuffer).

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebConfig  implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new ByteBufferToUUIDConverter());
    }
}
```

and dummy code of conversion

```java
public class ByteBufferToUUIDConverter implements Converter<ByteBuffer, UUID>, ConditionalConverter {
    private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ByteBufferToUUIDConverter.class);

    @Override
    public UUID convert(ByteBuffer source) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        logger.debug(":TypeDescriptor " + sourceType + ", " + targetType);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying wrapping up a `ByteBuffer` and its subclasses, I found a more simple solution.

1. Change `UUID` in the `@Entity` to `byte[]`
2. Delete useless classes.